# Counting characters in file in hexadecimal

Tags: c

I am trying to count the number of characters in a file and show them in hex.
An example:

5 instances of 'a'

'n' instances of ','

I do not want to output the characters that have not appered in the file and therefore not in my array. I would like to output the instances that are in the file.

I am not sure how to print for each instance that has occurred since I do not want to output the '0' instances of 'something'.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    int c;
    FILE *f = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    int totalchars[256] = { 0 };
    while ((c = getc(f)) != EOF) {
        if (totalchars[c] == 0)
            totalchars[c] = 1;
        else
            totalchars[c]++;

    } // while

    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        printf("%d instances of character %x\n", totalchars[i], c);

    return 0;
}
```

I know when printing, c is at the end of file so it will print ffffffff. I'm not sure how to output what I want.

Comment: always check (!=NULL) the returned value from `fopen()` to assure the operation was successful

Comment: never access beyond `argv[0]` without first checking `argc` to assure the command line parameter was actually entered.

Answer (score 4):

First, you don't need

```
if (totalchars[c] == 0)
    totalchars[c] = 1;
else
    totalchars[c]++;
```

Just say

```
totalchars[c]++;
```

Adding 1 will change a 0 to a 1 just as well as it will change (say) a 5 into a 6.  I assume you put the `if (totalchars[c] == 0)` test here because you didn't want to print counts of 0, but it's misplaced.  (See below.)

Second, you need

```
for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    printf("%d instances of character %x\n", totalchars[i], i);
```

so that, for each of the (up to) 256 slots in the array, you print the character that's counted for that slot (`i`), not repeat the last, EOF character you read from the file (`c`).

Finally, it's when you're printing out the array that it's time to test for counts that are 0, and suppress them.  So it will look like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    if(totalchars[i] != 0) {
        printf("%d instances of character %x\n", totalchars[i], i);
    }
}
```

---

Addendum: In answer to your followon question, the output might be more useful if it also included the character as itself:

```
        printf("%d instances of character %x: %c\n", totalchars[i], i, i);
```

This has the slight disadvantage, though, that it will try to print special characters such as space, tab, and newline as themselves, which won't always look quite right.

Comment: @guy I thought you wanted it in hexadecimal!  But see my amended answer.

Comment: Minor, better to use `UCHAR_MAX+1` than 256.  At a minimum, it is self documenting.

Comment: is that for the null character?

Comment: @guy No, it's for the possibility of a machine with something other than 8-bit bytes, meaning something other than 256 characters.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong variable, be careful when copying and pasting

```
printf("%d instances of character %c\n", totalchars[i], i);
/*                                                      ^
 *                                   should be `i' not `c'
 */
```